# ¿Cómo mostrar un ProgressBar mientras se obtiene una respuesta del servidor?

Tags: android

Tengo un `asynctask` el cual obtiene una serie de datos, ¿Cómo podría mostrar un `ProgressBar` mientras el servidor devuelve una respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

#### Mostrar Progressbar con un AsyncTask:

> ¿Como podria mostrar un progress bar mientras el servidor devuelve una
> respuesta?

Los datos se deben mostrar por medio del método `onProgressUpdate()` del `AsyncTask`:

```
 @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {                
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
```

Para ejemplo tenemos un layout que contiene un botón que inicia el AsyncTask y muestra el ProgressBar, agregamos un TextView para mostrar el progreso de forma más detallada:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Hello StackOverflow.com!" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Progress Dialog"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </ProgressBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView txt;
    Integer counter = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgress);
        btn.setText("Inicia!");
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter = 1;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnProgress:
                        new MyAsyncTask().execute(10);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            for (; counter <= params[0]; counter++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress(counter);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "Tarea completa!. =)";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txt.setText(result);
            btn.setText("Reinicia");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txt.setText("Tarea ejecutandose...");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            txt.setText("Ejecutandose..." +  values[0]);
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Al da click en el botón iniciará el `AsyncTask` (`MyAsyncTask`) y podras desplegar los resultados en el `TextView` mientras el `ProgressBar` indica su ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes cambiar el estilo de tu `ProgressBar` por `progressBarStyleHorizontal`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone">
</ProgressBar>
```

de esta forma podrás ver como se va llenando la barra de progreso horizontal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma de implementar el progreso es un con un `ProgressDialog` y `Asyntask` como en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
public class GetCoordenadaDir extends AsyncTask<String, String, Map<String,Double>> {
private Context contexto;
private ProgressDialog proceso;
public GetCoordenadaDir(Context context, String Dir) {
        this.contexto = context;

}



@Override
protected  Map<String,Double> doInBackground(String... params) {
   //Tu codigo
proceso.setMessage("Ya casi terminamos");
///MAs codigo
proceso.setMessage("Se paciente falta poco");
//Mucho mas codigo
proceso.setMessage("TERMINAMOS WIII");
    return datos;  //Esta variable no existe solo es de ejemeplo que tengo que retornal algo
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        proceso = new ProgressDialog(contexto);
        proceso.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        proceso.setMessage("Carcando Coordenadas Taller");
        proceso.setCancelable(false);
        proceso.show();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Map<String,Double> doubles) {

        proceso.dismiss();
}
}
```

Como te das cuenta el progressdialog lo instancio en el metodo `onPreExecute`.

Preguta ya la he respondido en la siguiente ruta:[Android: Problema con ProgressBar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39225/android-problema-con-progressbar/39245#39245)

Comment: Alguien le ha dado al copy paste.

Comment: Me descubrieron :(

Comment: hahahaha!!!!!!!! pensé era mi respuesta me la han plagiado! =P

Answer (score 0):

Yo en una clase solo tenia mi AsyncTask entonces lo que hise en ese caso fue pasar como parametro en el constructor donde se cuentra tu AsyncTask el Contexto y finalmente llamas a tus elementos que seria el ProgressBar que en mi caso en un FrameLayout y listo.

```
    public class SearchData extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, CheckIn> {//creo una atrea en segundo plano

    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    Context context;
    EditText editText;
    public SearchData(Context context, EditText editText) {
        this.context = context;
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    public void setFrameLayout(FrameLayout frameLayout) {
        this.frameLayout = frameLayout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected CheckIn doInBackground(Object... params) {//ejecuta nuestras tareas principales
        //TODO AQUI VA TU FUNCIONALIDAD
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {//se ejecuta cada vez que llamamos a un metodo  desde el metodo doingBackground
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CheckIn result) {//se ejecuta cuando termina doingBackgroud()
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (result != null){
            Intent intentIndex = new Intent(context, IndexActivity.class);//Creo un intent
            context.startActivity(intentIndex);//inicio la actividad
        } else {
            editText.setText("");
        } //./else
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {//cuando se cancela el proceso

    }
}//./clase
```