# Barra de progreso o mensaje de espera, webview Android Studio

Tags: android, webview, progressbar

Tengo un activity con un webview donde muestro una pagina web externa, esta ocasionalmente demora en cargar así que me gustaría ponerle una barra de progreso o un mensaje, esto para evitar que el usuario piense que mas que demora es que la aplicación no esta funcionando.

Así he implementado el WebView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.portal_web);

    String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView01);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### **Como cargar pagina web en un WebView y se muestre una barra de progreso.**

Esto se puede realizar implementando un `WebViewClient` a tu `WebView` y mediante el método [onPageFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) determina que la página has sido cargada completamente, en ese momento eliminas el dialogo mediante el método `dismiss()` del `ProgressBar`.

```
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //Obtiene referencia en Layout de WebView.
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    //Carga página.
    webView.loadUrl("http://es.stackoverflow.com");
   //Define WebViewClient() para poder leer eventos que ocurren durante el cargado de contenido en el WebView.
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //elimina ProgressBar.
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Cuando el `WebView` este en proceso de carga del contenido se mostraría el `ProgressBar`, al termino desaparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso puedes cambiar el estilo para que se vea como una barra de progreso:

```
 progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como otra opción, puedes incluso implementar un `Asynctask` para mostrar el progreso de carga.

**[¿Cómo mostrar un ProgressBar mientras se obtiene una respuesta del servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39665/95)**

Answer (score 3):

lo que intentas hacer no es complicado, solamente tienes que sobrescribir el método **OnPageFinished**

```
  private void showProgressBar(){

     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    //ProgressDialog
    final ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Espera...");
    dialog.show();

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_uno);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
    progressDialog.show();

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://reygom.com/?s=&search-submit=Buscar&status=&location=&listing-type=casa&min=&max=&orderby=date&order=desc");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url){
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega una explicación a la respuesta, las respuestas de solo código se consideran de baja calidad.