# ¿Como sustituir ProgressDialog(obsoleto) por ProgressBar en retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Dado que `ProgressDialog` esta "deprecated" estoy intentando sustituir por un ProgressBar,tengo una actividad con una lista y estoy tratando de mostrar un ProgressBar antes de que se muestre la lista tras una consulta http con retrofit.

He usado "progressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible/Gone/Invisible)" pero se muestran una vez se termina de cargar la lista.

```
public class MisSolicitudes extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private String token = null;
    private ListView lvSolicitudes;
    private static final String TAG = "retrofit";
    private boolean clickable_item=true;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Context context=this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mis_solicitudes);
        clickable_item=true;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Cargando");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Consultando...");
        progressDialog.show();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        this.setTitle("Solicitudes");

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        token = preferences.getString("token", "null");

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        lvSolicitudes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.misSolicitudes);
        obtenerMisSolicitudes();
    }

    private void obtenerMisSolicitudes(){

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        map.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

        RestService serviceSolicitudes = retrofit.create(RestService.class);
        Call<List<SolicitudesDto>> misSolicituresRespuesta = serviceSolicitudes.comprobarSolicitudes(map);

        misSolicituresRespuesta.enqueue(new Callback<List<SolicitudesDto>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SolicitudesDto>> call, Response<List<SolicitudesDto>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){

                    final List<SolicitudesDto> misSolicitudes = response.body();

                    if(misSolicitudes.size()==0){
                        lvSolicitudes.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView_));
                    }

                    SolicitudesListAdapter adapter = new SolicitudesListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), misSolicitudes);
                    lvSolicitudes.setAdapter(adapter);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }else{
                    lvSolicitudes.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView_));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SolicitudesDto>> call, Throwable t) {

                lvSolicitudes.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView_));
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context=".....MisSolicitudes">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/misSolicitudes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyListView_"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="No se han encontrado"
        android:textAlignment="center">
    </TextView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu código iniciaría por asignar un id al contenedor principal que es el `ConstraintLayout` que es donde se mostraría el `ProgressBar`, por ejemplo asigna como id `container` :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    ...
    ...


    android:id="@+id/container">
```

Posteriormente elimina las referencias del `ProgressDialog`, y agrega el `ProgressBar`, revisa los comentarios en código :

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mis_solicitudes);
        clickable_item=true;

        /*progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Cargando");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Consultando...");
        progressDialog.show();*/

      /**************** ProgressBar *********************/

      ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        // Crea layout parameters para el ProgressBar
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //Define como indeterminado.
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        // Agrega el ProgressBar al Layout
        cl.addView(progressBar);

      /*****************************************/



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        this.setTitle("Solicitudes");

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        token = preferences.getString("token", "null");

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        lvSolicitudes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.misSolicitudes);
        obtenerMisSolicitudes();
    }
```

De esta forma se mostraría en tu `Activity`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso puedes cambiar el estilo para mostrarlo de forma horizontal,

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

similar a las aplicaciones Android:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso en el cual quitas el `ProgressDialog` al recibir la respuesta de la solicitud,

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

puedes cambiar la visibilidad del `ProgressBar` a invisible:

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

aplicado a tu código:

```
misSolicituresRespuesta.enqueue(new Callback<List<SolicitudesDto>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<SolicitudesDto>> call, Response<List<SolicitudesDto>> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){

            final List<SolicitudesDto> misSolicitudes = response.body();

            if(misSolicitudes.size()==0){
                lvSolicitudes.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView_));
            }

            SolicitudesListAdapter adapter = new SolicitudesListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), misSolicitudes);
            lvSolicitudes.setAdapter(adapter);
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else{
            lvSolicitudes.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView_));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<SolicitudesDto>> call, Throwable t) {

        lvSolicitudes.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView_));
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
});
```

---

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que podrías también implementar el cual muestra el progreso por medio de un `AsyncTask`.

[¿Cómo mostrar un ProgressBar mientras se obtiene una respuesta del servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39648/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-un-progressbar-mientras-se-obtiene-una-respuesta-del-servidor)

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta, he hecho los cambios en el código que me has propuesto. No me funcionaba, pero he probado con distintas versiones de Android y he comprobado que se debe a la versión del SO. Con Oreo funciona perfectamente pero con lollipop el spinner no aparece hasta que se carga la lista. No entiendo el motivo... (Supongo que se debe a los problemas de fragmentación de las distintas versiones Android).     PD: no te he votado negativamente

Comment: A partir de la Api 25 funciona, en versiones inferiores no. Es decir a partir de la api 25 cuando se ejecuta la actividad aparece el spinner y desaparece cuando se carga la lista. Con versiones inferiores el spinner no aparece ( si quito el "dismiss" el spinner aparece cuando se carga la lista")

Comment: @Jorgesys buena explicación. Una pregunta adicional: He leído que se aplica `GONE` para asegurar que el objeto que se oculta no ocupe espacio. ¿ El efecto de `INVISIBLE` es el mismo?

Comment: El efecto  `INVISIBLE` oculta la vista pero se conserva el espacio asignado,  a diferencia de `GONE` que elimina el espacio ocupado por la vista también.